# How do I log an array of values from a list of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, logging

I have an array of days where each day is divided into 30 minute chunks where each chunk is an object array. I want to get the value of the key "wake" for each chunk. If wake is false and then true I want to add 1 to a variable called sleepFrag and if "wake" is false I want to add 30 to a variable called sleepPeriod. I want to console log both of my variables, sleepPeriod and sleepFrag.

This is what the list I am trying to read from looks like(I only included two hours of two days, each "chunks" is divided into 24 hours and I don't know how many days there are):

```
 days = [
{
chunks: [
  {
    BM: 1,
    ID: 0,
    hour: "00",
    issue: 0,
    mealP: 30,
    timeMins: "00",
    wake: true
  },
  {
    BM: 0,
    ID: 1,
    hour: "00",
    issue: 0,
    mealP: 30,
    timeMins: "30",
    wake: true
  },
  {
    BM: 0,
    ID: 2,
    hour: "01",
    issue: 0,
    mealP: 0,
    timeMins: "00",
    wake: false
  },
  {
    BM: 0,
    ID: 3,
    hour: "01",
    issue: 3,
    mealP: 0,
    timeMins: "30",
    wake: false
  }

    ],
epoch: 1563163200
},
{
chunks: [
  {
    BM: 0,
    ID: 0,
    hour: "00",
    issue: 0,
    mealP: 0,
    timeMins: "00",
    wake: true
  },
  {
    BM: 0,
    ID: 1,
    hour: "00",
    issue: 0,
    mealP: 0,
    timeMins: "30",
    wake: true
  },
  {
    BM: 0,
    ID: 2,
    hour: "01",
    issue: 0,
    mealP: 0,
    timeMins: "00",
    wake: true
  },
```

and so on

Here is what I tried already:

```
function getSleep(daysIn){
    sleepFrag = 0
    sleepPeriod = 0
    for (chunk=0; chunk < days.length; chunk++){
        for(element=0; element< days[chunk].length; element++){
            if(days[element-1].wake==false)&&(days[element].wake==true){
                sleepFrag+=1
            }
            else if (days[element].wake==false){
                sleepPeriod+=30
            }

        }
        console.log("this is the sleep amount for day"+chunk+":"sleepPeriod)
        console.log("this is the number of sleep fragments for day"+chunk+":"sleepFrag)
    }
    console.log("this is the total number of sleep fragments :"+sleepFrag)
    console.log("this is the total amount of sleep :"+sleepPeriod)
}
console.log("sleep fragments and sleep periods")
getSleep(days)
```

I get no log on the console and no errors.
I expect to get:

sleep fragments and sleep periods

this is the sleep amount for day (the "chunks" representing the day im in): (sleepPeriod for that day)

this is the number of sleep fragments for day(the "chunks" representing the day im in): (sleepFrag for that day)

this is the total number of sleep fragments :(number of sleep fragments)
this is the total amount of sleep :(amount of sleep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your function is actually correct.. but the code writing is very poor..
No var declaration, no semicolon (;), etc.. 
Here is the refined function:

```
function getSleep(daysIn){
    var sleepFrag = 0
    var sleepPeriod = 0
    for (var i=0; i < daysIn.length; i++){
        var day = daysIn[i];
        var chunksOfTheDay = day.chunks;
        for(var j=1; j < chunksOfTheDay.length; j++){
            if((chunksOfTheDay[j-1].wake === false) && (chunksOfTheDay[j].wake === true)){
                sleepFrag+=1
            }
            else if (chunksOfTheDay[j].wake === false){
                sleepPeriod+=30
            }

        }
        console.log("this is the sleep amount for day"+i+":"+sleepPeriod);
        console.log("this is the number of sleep fragments for day"+i+":"+sleepFrag);
    }
    console.log("this is the total number of sleep fragments :"+sleepFrag);
    console.log("this is the total amount of sleep :"+sleepPeriod);
}
console.log("sleep fragments and sleep periods");
getSleep(days);
```

Comment: This actually worked!! thank you so much. You're amazing.